# Android onCreate called twice after phone reboot, makes fragment stop working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I have written an application for Android that has an issue (crash) when it is launched *immediately* (with in 5 seconds or so) after the phone is rebooted. Due to one reason or another, the OnCreate method is called for a second time. I thought this may have been the problem, but after researching this, I found out the android system may recall onCreate after start up as it is still starting system services - such as getting the "MCM".

In my application in the MainActivity I have a statically bound fragment that is bound through XML. The fragment has code in it that checks that location permissions were granted:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

The problem is, this.getContext() returns null! It definitely has something to do with the fact onCreate is being called more than once, because when the phone is not booting and onCreate is only called once the application works perfectly!

Here is the only reference I make to the fragment in my onCreate method in the **mainActivity**:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragMap = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mv_1);

    if (fragMap instanceof FragmentMap)
    {
        theMap = (FragmentMap) fragMap;
    }
```

Here is the fragment bound through **XML**:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/mv_1"
    android:name="com.sunhillo.personneltrackerv002.FragmentMap"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"/>
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide! I am still new to Android programming, and am attempting to learn the ins and outs!

Comment: In which method of the Fragment do you have the permission check?

Comment: @jaibatrik It is in my compareLocations method. This method compares the location of the Maps Camera compared to the users current location on the map. I also have checks elsewhere but this is the first one called. If I am not mistaken it is necessary to check that you still have permissions before creating a location manager (for the purpose of this application). I create a location manager in the fragment for the purpose of recentering the map to the user...

Answer (score 0):

If your ultimate aim is to access the location permissions, simply add these permissions in manifest file. And if you wish to perform this check via java, don't add this to individual fragments. Add this syntax only to the MainActivity java file that refers to the fragments. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use launch mode Single Task or Single top which will avoid calling multiple onCreate and you should use getApplicationContext().